# ansible.vars.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'public_ip'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

Why does this task (from [Best way to launch aws ec2 instances with ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227140/best-way-to-launch-aws-ec2-instances-with-ansible)):

```
  - name: Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to the local host group (located inside the directory)
    local_action: lineinfile 
                  dest="./hosts" 
                  regexp={{ item.public_ip }} 
                  insertafter="[webserver]" line={{ item.public_ip }}
    with_items: ec2.instances
```

create this error?

```
TASK [Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to the local host group (located inside the directory)] ********************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'ansible.vars.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'public_ip'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/Users/snowcrash/ansible-ec2/ec2_launch.yml': line 55, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n      - name: Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to the local host group (located inside the directory)\n        ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 6):

the issue is here

```
with_items: ec2.instances
```

It should be:

```
with_items: '{{ ec2.instances }}'
```

ec2 is variable referencing a dictionary so you will need to reference it with the proper syntax

Comment: Thanks!! That helped

Answer (score 1):

Put:

```
  - debug: msg="{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

before that code and inspect what are the contents of that variable. It should be a list of dictionaries that each have a member `public_ip`, otherwise you'd get the message that you're getting.

Comment: I'm launching 1 instance. There is a variable `public_ip` and it has a value.